# How do I solve the "cannot read property ... of undefined" with out using try/catch?

Tags: javascript

This function is designed to count all items in array of a specific type. However, when there are zero elements of a certain type I receive the "cannot read property ... of undefined" error. I have tried to fix it using the typeof keyword, but it hasn't worked. Is my syntax correct and how would I fix this issue?

```
function typeCount(type){
    if (typeof (base.getbyType(type)) === "undefined"){ return 0;  }
    else { return base.getbyType(type).length;}
}
var pCount = typeCount('pen');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply have `getbyType` return an empty array on no matches - then no check is needed:

```
function typeCount(type){
    return base.getbyType(type).length;
}
```

However, if the posted codes throws the exception then the error is *elsewhere* - as in, not inherently with the `.length` access. Consider these possible causes:

- `base` itself evaluates to undefined. The correct fix for this is to make sure `base` *cannot* be undefined. A guard here just hides the problem and should likely *not* be used!
- The exception is thrown from within `getbyType`. This means the function is broken - fix it.
- `getbyType` is not consistent and returns undefined only-sometimes. This means the function is broken - fix it.

And, if the `getbyType` insists on *not* returning an empty array for no matches, use a temporary variable. This also avoids the unnecessary duplicate work that is done by the original code.

```
function typeCount(type){
    var res = base.getbyType(type);
    return (typeof res === "undefined") ? 0 : res.length;
}
```

Or, not caring if it is strictly undefined (what good is `null.length`?) ..

```
function typeCount(type){
    var res = base.getbyType(type);
    return res ? res.length : 0;
}
```

Or, if we're feeling "clever" (note that `getbyType` is still only called once)..

```
function typeCount(type){
    return (base.getbyType(type) || []).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
function typeCount(type){
    if (base.getbyType(type) === undefined){ return 0;  }//modified code here
    else { return base.getbyType(type).length;}
}
var pCount = typeCount('pen');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function typeCount(type){
    if (base && base.getbyType && typeof (base.getbyType(type)) === "undefined"){ return 0;  }
    else { return base.getbyType(type).length;}
}
var pCount = typeCount('pen');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `base` or `base.getbyType` undefined

```
function typeCount(type){
    if (typeof base === 'undefined' || !base.getbyType || base.getbyType(type) === "undefined"){ return 0;  }else { return base.getbyType(type).length;}
}
var pCount = typeCount('pen');
```